# User consent to stop the playing audio

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, xna-4.0

Windows Phone 7.5 / Silverlight app

If user is playing music / radio on their phone and they try to launch my application, I want to give user an option to stop the currently playing option.

**Working fine:**
The message popup shows up fine. When I select Cancel, the popup closes, the music keeps playing and my app starts/works as normal.

**Issue:**
If I select Ok i.e. to stop the currently playing music on phone, the music stops but at the same time my app also exits.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Here is the code I am using. I call this method on launching:

```
private void CheckAudio()
        {
            if (FMRadio.Instance.PowerMode == RadioPowerMode.On)
            {
                MessageBoxResult Choice;
                Choice = MessageBox.Show("For better user experience with this application it is recommended you stop other audio applications. Do you want to stop the radio?", "Radio is currently playing!", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                if (Choice == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    FMRadio.Instance.PowerMode = RadioPowerMode.Off;
                }
            }
            if (MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Playing)
            {
                MessageBoxResult Choice;
                Choice = MessageBox.Show("For better user experience with this application it is recommended you stop other audio/video applications. Do you want to stop the MediaPlayer?", "MediaPlayer is currently playing!", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                if (Choice == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    MediaPlayer.Stop();
                }
            }
        }
```

**Update:**
I posted my solution below. Do let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: If you fixed your issue you should post your solution & mark as an answer to help others down-the-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following error was being thrown:

> FrameworkDispatcher.Update has not been called. Regular
>   FrameworkDispatcher. Update calls are necessary for fire and forget
>   sound effects and framework events to function correctly.

So I added this code and now it is working fine. Now upon clicking OK, the music player stops and my app launches fine. I call the SetupTimer method from InitializeComponent in App.xaml.cs

```
private GameTimer gameTimer; 

private void SetupTimer()
{

gameTimer = new GameTimer();
gameTimer.UpdateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33);

// Call FrameworkDispatcher.Update to update the XNA Framework internals.
gameTimer.Update += new EventHandler<GameTimerEventArgs>(gameTimer_Update); //delegate { try { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); } catch { } };

// Start the GameTimer running.
gameTimer.Start();

// Prime the pump or we'll get an exception.
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();

}

void gameTimer_Update(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
{
try { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); }
catch { }
}
```

If anybody sees any problem/issue with the above please do let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Its so sad that there is only one solution i have found after long searching. +1.